# PLSQL Procedural Logic

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to write a PL/SQL function that:

1. Uses only numeric datatypes and functions-no VARCHAR2, CHAR, CLOB, XML, etc.
   "   In other words, character/string functions such as REVERSE, SUBSTR, etc are not to be used in your solution.
2. Accepts a PLS_INTEGER parameter
3. If the provided value is less than or equal to zero throws application error -20001 and provides a good error message
4. Returns a PLS_INTEGER value that has the digits from the input parameter in reverse order. If the input value ends in one or more zeroes those zeroes will not appear in the returned numeric value, since they would be leading zeroes.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
create or replace function test_reverse
    (p_input in pls_integer) 
    return pls_integer 
is
    p_num pls_integer := 0; 
    p_in_num pls_integer := 0; 
    p_out_num pls_integer := 0; 
begin 
    p_num := p_input; 
    loop 
        exit when p_num p_in_num := mod(p_num,10); 
        p_out_num := (p_out_num * 10) + p_in_num;
        p_num := trunc(p_num / 10); 
    end loop; 
    return p_out_num; 
end;
```

Comment: You're welcome in advance. What have you tried so far.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_REVERSE 
(P_INPUT IN PLS_INTEGER) 
RETURN PLS_INTEGER IS P_NUM 
PLS_INTEGER := 0; 
P_IN_NUM PLS_INTEGER := 0; 
P_OUT_NUM PLS_INTEGER := 0; 
BEGIN P_NUM := P_INPUT; 
LOOP EXIT WHEN P_NUM P_IN_NUM := MOD(P_NUM,10); 
P_OUT_NUM := (P_OUT_NUM * 10) + P_IN_NUM; 
P_NUM := TRUNC(P_NUM / 10); 
END LOOP; 
RETURN P_OUT_NUM; 
END;

Comment: Please add any code to your question, not as comments, and describe what isn't working. Also if you could lowercase it to improve readability that would be lovely.

Comment: Obviously a homework question. But an interesting problem, and one which requires some non-obvious knowledge of Oracle SQL functions, so worth an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to turn 1234 into 4321. The string-y solution (admittedly using an undocumented built-in) is simplicity itself: `to_number(reverse(to_char(1234)))`. Sticking to numeric datatypes is more cumbersome. My solution is very procedural: undoubtedly more elegant solutions exist.

Anyway, to turn 1234 into 4321 we need to generate 1 + 20 + 300 + 4000. My solution isolates each value in turn and multiplies by the appropriate power of ten.  To isolate the values we use `trunc()` with a negative value. This rounds down the number to the left of the decimal point. Thus, `trunc(1234,-3)` produces `1000`. To convert this into the required value we multiply by ten to the power of minus three. Thus `1000 * 10(-3) = 1`.

The function iterates through the numbers. Having converted 1000 to 1 we calculate the remainder, `1234 - 1000 = 234`. So now we need to isolate the 200 and convert it to 20; that is `trunc(234, -2)` and `power(200, -1)`. So we can the offset fed into `trunc()` decrements by 1 and the exponent fed into  `power()` increments by 2.

Here is a working function (very loosely based on the one you posted):

```
create or replace function test_reverse
    (p_input in pls_integer) 
    return pls_integer 
is
    p_out_num pls_integer := 0;
    offset    pls_integer;
    tgt       pls_integer;
    rmdr      pls_integer;
    exp       pls_integer;
begin 
    rmdr := p_input;
    offset := length(p_input)-1;
    exp := -offset;
    loop 
        tgt := trunc(rmdr, -offset);
        p_out_num := p_out_num + (tgt * power(10, exp));
        exp := exp + 2;
        rmdr := rmdr - tgt;
        exit when offset = 0;
        offset := offset-1;
    end loop; 
    return p_out_num; 
end test_reverse; 
/
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo (free Oracle Technet account required, alas)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gk35f64zf16ge4irmleu87ipw). That doesn't feature the parameter validation but it is straightforward enough:

```
create or replace function test_reverse
    (p_input in pls_integer) 
    return pls_integer 
is
    p_out_num pls_integer := 0;
    offset    pls_integer;
    tgt       pls_integer;
    rmdr      pls_integer;
    exp       pls_integer;
begin 
    if p_input <= 0 then
         raise_application_error(-20001
              'invalid input: ' || || ' must be greater than zero.'
         );
    end if; 
    rmdr := p_input;
    ....
```

Comment: might there also be a way to salvage the op's question  out of this abyss of downvotes ?

Comment: To be honest not much I think the downvoters responded to what they saw as a lazy "do my homework" question. I have addressed @williamrobertson's comment but that's about all the polishing I'm comfortable with. It is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I like the use of the modulo function as the op suggested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_reverse (
    p_input IN PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN PLS_INTEGER 
IS
    remain   PLS_INTEGER := p_input;
    retval   PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    IF p_input < 1 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001,'error: input must me greater than 0');
    END IF;
    LOOP
        retval := retval * 10 + MOD(remain,10);
        remain := trunc(remain / 10);
        EXIT WHEN remain = 0;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN retval;
END;
/
```

This also avoids the use of the length() function which to my taste feels a bit "stringish", even if it operates on numbers.