# how to extract thousands and units from a number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a number for example `1550`,I need to get thousands and units from this number.

To extract thousand I am using the following formula:

```
Select TRUNC(1550/1000) FROM DUAL
```

I will get `1`, now I need to get `550` from the above number.

What will be the best formula to get the remaining units from the amount, please also consider that the amount can be `550`, `12501`, `50`, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You may find it helpful to read [both the answers in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49950142/146325). They solve a slightly different problem but they will give you an insight into the techniques available to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `mod()` function:

```
select mod(1550, 1000)
```

The specific operation is called the modulus, and it calculates the remainder.  This can be a little tricky if you have negative numbers.  Do you want `mod(-1, 5)` to be -1 or 4?

Depending on what you want, you can also calculate the value directly:

```
select 1550 - floor(1550/1000)*1000
```